# How can I load a controller action from loading up a blank URL in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'd like to be able to load up a frontend controller action from a default URL eg. [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) and have it load up the frontend siteController::actionMain().

Is there any changes I can make in my Yii2 project to acheive this?

I tried using a forward in my hosting, however it left me unable to access the backend of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to do it using URLManager?

```
'urlManager' => [
 'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
 'showScriptName' => false,
 'rules' => ['GET ' => 'site/main'],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [defaultRoute](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-application#$defaultRoute-detail) property for Web Application. You can set it as "site/main"

Answer (score 0):

I found that this was solved by using a .htaccess file to point to frontend/web

then a defaultRoute to point to the controller

then a $defaultAction class variable on the controller

Comment: Could you add the complete code that you used to resolve your question so that if someone else came across it, could quickly interpret your response? I think that would be pretty helpful.